# Qrcode breaking content on Print Page with NgxPrinter Angular

Tags: angular, qr-code

How can i prevent my qrcode to break on the end of page?
im using ngxprinter to print the content, calling by div.

here is my code:

**HTML:**

```js
<div id="example class="container-fluid my-auto" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <div class="row" [attr.style]="row">
        <div *ngFor="let res of response">
            <qrcode [qrdata]="res.code" [width]="qrSize" [errorCorrectionLevel]="'M'"[elementType]="'img'"></qrcode>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
print(){
    this.printerService.printDiv(`example`);
}
```

Actually, the result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxw7l.png)

Comment: could you add more details? A screenshot of the desired solution may help us more.

Comment: Hi, i think i get it. the problem was the 'row', because this component doesnt break in the end of each page.. as i wanted. so i removed then, and now my qrcodes are displayed just with the style 'display:inline-block', and it works well without the row class.